# Divergence of the Berry connection

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, topology, berry-pancharatnam-phase

Given the Berry connection
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{\mathcal{A}}(\mathbf{R}) = i \langle u(\mathbf{R}) | \nabla_\mathbf{R} | u(\mathbf{R}) \rangle,
\end{equation}

the Berry curvature can be written as its curl,
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{\Omega}(\mathbf{R}) = \nabla_\mathbf{R} \times \boldsymbol{\mathcal{A}}(\mathbf{R}).
\end{equation}

The Chern number measures the ammount of curl inside a region
\begin{equation}
C = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \oint_S \boldsymbol{\Omega} \cdot d\mathbf{S}.
\end{equation}

What about the divergence of the Berry connection,
\begin{equation}
\nabla_\mathbf{R} \cdot \boldsymbol{\mathcal{A}} (\mathbf{R}) = ~?
\end{equation}
Does it correspond to a meaningful object? Is it associated with a topological charge?

Comment: Are your $k$ indices on your $u_k$ the same as your $k$ indices on your $\nabla_k$?

Comment: They are not exacly indices, but rather specify that the derivatives are in k-space. I will try to improve the notation, thanks for the headsup

Comment: Well, have you considered what happens to the divergence of $A$ under a gauge transformation? I guess this will answer your question.

Comment: As I understand we have $\boldsymbol{\mathcal{A}} \rightarrow \boldsymbol{\mathcal{A}} + \nabla f$, meaning $\boldsymbol{\mathcal{A}}$ is not gauge invariant. However, the Chern-Simons form is also not gauge invariant, but it can still be used to construct a topological invariant in odd dimensions (https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.1505.03535). Is there some fundamental reason why we cannot do a similar thing with objects making use of the divergence of the Berry connection?

Answer (score 1):

(I don't have the reputation to add this as a comment, apologies.)

In differential form notation, the divergence is written as 'd$*$', i.e., it involves the metric, because of the Hodge star.

Generally, constructing a topological invariant from a metric dependent object is non-trivial (you would need some further symmetry). Therefore, I don't think it is generally possible.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Is the Berry curvature metric-independent then?

Comment: Defined as the exterior derivative of the connection, yes.

Comment: However, there are subtleties involved in this definition in topologically nontrivial spaces, and you need to bring fibre bundles into the game.
I recommend skimming through topology in physics by Nakahara, to get a better idea of these concepts.

Comment: In particular, see section 10.6.2 of the 2nd edition of the book.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look